# How to find out whether dynamic programming's answer is the optimal answer or not?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

what sort of algorithm should I use beside to find out whether dynamic programming's answer to the problem is the optimal answer or not?
could you suggest some papers to help me find out that?

Comment: I think you first have to define the problem and "optimal".

Comment: Can you give an example where you suspect dynamic programming would give you a non-optimal answer? I don't quite get your question, because by definition, I believe that if your problem can be stated as a dynamic programming one, then dynamic programming will give you an optimal answer (provided you can compute it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic programming approach to a problem will usually get the correct answer - i.e. find the true minimum cost answer - but it is not usually guaranteed to be the way of solving the problem that uses the minimum amount of cpu or memory.

There are many cases where we do not know if our method of solving a problem uses the minimum possible amount of cpu. One example, where dynamic program is one of the more efficient methods known, but is not proved to be the most efficient possible method is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no algorithm that tells you whether a given dynamic programming solution is optimal.

See the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for research on a closely related question.

Comment: It seems to me that the question itself is flawed, though. Isn't it correct that if a problem can be stated as a dynamic programming problem, then dynamic programming's solution will be optimal? The only problem I can see is the case of a problem that is a DP problem, but maybe cannot be solved because it doesn't terminate (which is probably what you meant with the Halting Problem).

Answer (score 0):

If by your question you are meaning: "How do I find if my Dynamic programming is correctly implemented?" You can solve the problem also by backtracking wich is simple to implement and always gives the best solution. You can try both backtracking and dynamic programming for the same small data inputs and if the outputs are identical then you can strongly suspect that you dynamic programming implementation is correct. 
Otherwise dynamic programming always gives the optimal answer, but not all problems ca be solved by DP and of course not all DP progrems can be solved using the same state and/or recurence.